# Gibberish in Google Maps in Codename One

Tags: google-maps, intellij-idea, codenameone

[Gibberish in Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nIFt.png)

I am working on an IOS app in Codenameone (in Intellij), and programed an interface for users to use google maps within my app. However, when they start to search for places or navigate in street view, I receive a ton of gibberish on my iOS simulator (See screenshot below). Has anyone run into this issue and if so, have you found as shown?

```
public class PetBnBApp {

    private static final String HTML_API_KEY = "AIzaSyBWeRU02YUYPdwRuMFyTKIXUbHjq6e35Gw";
    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;


    private Form home;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature

        try {
            Resources theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(theme.getTheme(theme.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));
            Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION);
            UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setMenuBarClass(SideMenuBar.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    MapContainer.MapObject sydney;
    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form maps = new Form("Native Maps Test");
        maps.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer(HTML_API_KEY);
        //final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer();
        //42.3040009,-71.5040407
        cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(42.3040009, -71.5040407));//this breaks the code //because the Google map is not loaded yet
        cnt.addMapListener(new MapListener() {

            @Override
            public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zoom, Coord center) {
                System.out.println("Map position updated: zoom="+zoom+", Center="+center);
            }

        });

        cnt.addLongPressListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Long press");
            ToastBar.showMessage("Received longPress at "+e.getX()+", "+e.getY(), FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION);
        });
        cnt.addTapListener(e->{
            ToastBar.showMessage("Received tap at "+e.getX()+", "+e.getY(), FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION);
        });

        int maxZoom = cnt.getMaxZoom();
        System.out.println("Max zoom is "+maxZoom);
        Button btnMoveCamera = new Button("Move Camera");
        btnMoveCamera.addActionListener(e->{
            cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(-33.867, 151.206));
        });
        Style s = new Style();
        s.setFgColor(0xff0000);
        s.setBgTransparency(0);
        FontImage markerImg = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE, s, 3);

        Button btnAddMarker = new Button("Add Marker");
        btnAddMarker.addActionListener(e->{

            cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(41.889, -87.622));
            cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false), cnt.getCameraPosition(), "Hi marker", "Optional long description", new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Bounding box is "+cnt.getBoundingBox());
                    ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked the marker", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
                }
            });

        });

        Button btnAddPath = new Button("Add Path");
        btnAddPath.addActionListener(e->{

            cnt.addPath(
                    cnt.getCameraPosition(),
                    new Coord(-33.866, 151.195), // Sydney
                    new Coord(-18.142, 178.431),  // Fiji
                    new Coord(21.291, -157.821),  // Hawaii
                    new Coord(37.423, -122.091)  // Mountain View
            );
        });

        Button panTo = new Button("Pan To");
        panTo.addActionListener(e->{
            //bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng('66.057878', '-22.579047')); // Iceland
            //bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng('37.961952', '43.878878')); // Turkey

            Coord c1 = new Coord(42.3040432, -71.5045936);
            Coord c2 = new Coord(49.2577142, -123.1941149);
            //Coord center = new Coord(c1.getLatitude()/2 +  c2.getLatitude() / 2, c1.getLongitude()/2 + c2.getLongitude()/2 );
            Coord center = new Coord(49.1110928, -122.9414646);

            float zoom = cnt.getZoom();

            boolean[] finished = new boolean[1];
            cnt.addMapListener(new MapListener() {

                @Override
                public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zoom, Coord c) {

                    if (Math.abs(c.getLatitude() - center.getLatitude()) > .001 || Math.abs(c.getLongitude() - center.getLongitude()) > .001) {
                        return;
                    }
                    finished[0] = true;
                    synchronized(finished) {
                        final MapListener fthis = this;
                        Display.getInstance().callSerially(()->{
                            cnt.removeMapListener(fthis);
                        });
                        finished.notify();
                    }

                }

            });
            cnt.zoom(center, (int)zoom);
            while (!finished[0]) {
                Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(()->{
                    while (!finished[0]) {
                        Util.wait(finished, 100);
                    }
                });
            }
            BoundingBox box = cnt.getBoundingBox();
            if (!box.contains(c1) || !box.contains(c2)) {
                while (!box.contains(c1) || !box.contains(c2)) {
                    if (!box.contains(c1)) {
                        System.out.println("Box "+box+" doesn't contain "+c1);
                    }
                    if (!box.contains(c1)) {
                        System.out.println("Box "+box+" doesn't contain "+c2);
                    }
                    zoom -= 1;
                    final boolean[] done = new boolean[1];

                    final int fzoom = (int)zoom;
                    cnt.addMapListener(new MapListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zm, Coord center) {

                            if (zm == fzoom) {
                                final MapListener fthis = this;
                                Display.getInstance().callSerially(()->{
                                    cnt.removeMapListener(fthis);
                                });

                                done[0] = true;
                                synchronized(done) {
                                    done.notify();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    cnt.zoom(center, (int)zoom);
                    while (!done[0]) {
                        Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(()->{
                            while (!done[0]) {
                                Util.wait(done, 100);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    box = cnt.getBoundingBox();
                    System.out.println("Zoom now "+zoom);

                }
            } else if (box.contains(c1) && box.contains(c2)) {
                while (box.contains(c1) && box.contains(c2)) {
                    zoom += 1;
                    final boolean[] done = new boolean[1];

                    final int fzoom = (int)zoom;
                    cnt.addMapListener(new MapListener() {
                        public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zm, Coord center)  {
                            if (zm == fzoom) {
                                final MapListener fthis = this;
                                Display.getInstance().callSerially(()->{
                                    cnt.removeMapListener(fthis);
                                });
                                done[0] = true;
                                synchronized(done) {
                                    done.notify();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    cnt.zoom(center, (int)zoom);
                    while (!done[0]) {
                        Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(()->{
                            while (!done[0]) {
                                Util.wait(done, 100);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    box = cnt.getBoundingBox();

                }
                zoom -= 1;
                cnt.zoom(center, (int)zoom);
                cnt.addTapListener(null);
            }

        });

        Button testCoordPositions = $(new Button("Test Coords"))
                .addActionListener(e->{
                    Coord topLeft = cnt.getCoordAtPosition(0, 0);
                    System.out.println("Top Left is "+topLeft+" -> "+cnt.getScreenCoordinate(topLeft) +" Should be (0,0)");
                    Coord bottomRight = cnt.getCoordAtPosition(cnt.getWidth(), cnt.getHeight());
                    System.out.println("Bottom right is "+bottomRight+" -> "+cnt.getScreenCoordinate(bottomRight) + " Should be "+cnt.getWidth()+", "+cnt.getHeight());
                    Coord bottomLeft = cnt.getCoordAtPosition(0, cnt.getHeight());
                    System.out.println("Bottom Left is "+bottomLeft+" -> "+cnt.getScreenCoordinate(bottomLeft) + " Should be 0, "+cnt.getHeight());
                    Coord topRight = cnt.getCoordAtPosition(cnt.getWidth(), 0);
                    System.out.println("Top right is "+topRight + " -> "+cnt.getScreenCoordinate(topRight)+ " Should be "+cnt.getWidth()+", 0");
                    Coord center = cnt.getCoordAtPosition(cnt.getWidth()/2, cnt.getHeight()/2);
                    System.out.println("Center is "+center+" -> "+cnt.getScreenCoordinate(center)+", should be "+(cnt.getWidth()/2)+", "+(cnt.getHeight()/2));
                    EncodedImage encImg = EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false);
                    cnt.addMarker(encImg, topLeft,"Top Left", "Top Left", null);
                    cnt.addMarker(encImg, topRight, "Top Right", "Top Right", null);
                    cnt.addMarker(encImg, bottomRight, "Bottom Right", "Bottom Right", null);
                    cnt.addMarker(encImg, bottomLeft, "Bottom Left", "Bottom Left", null);
                    cnt.addMarker(encImg, center, "Center", "Center", null);


                })
                .asComponent(Button.class);

        Button toggleTopMargin = $(new Button("Toggle Margin"))
                .addActionListener(e->{
                    int marginTop = $(cnt).getStyle().getMarginTop();
                    if (marginTop < Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 3) {
                        $(cnt).selectAllStyles().setMargin(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 3, 0, 0, 0);
                    } else {
                        $(cnt).selectAllStyles().setMargin(0,0,0,0);
                    }
                    $(cnt).getComponentForm().revalidate();
                })
                .asComponent(Button.class);


        Button btnClearAll = new Button("Clear All");
        btnClearAll.addActionListener(e->{
            cnt.clearMapLayers();
        });

        MapContainer.MapObject mo = cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false), new Coord(-33.866, 151.195), "test", "test", e->{
            System.out.println("Marker clicked");
            cnt.removeMapObject(sydney);
        });
        sydney = mo;
        System.out.println("MO is "+mo);
        mo = cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false), new Coord(-18.142, 178.431), "test", "test",e->{
            System.out.println("Marker clicked");
        });
        System.out.println("MO is "+mo);
        cnt.addTapListener(e->{
            if (tapDisabled) {
                return;
            }
            tapDisabled = true;
            TextField enterName = new TextField();
            Container wrapper = BoxLayout.encloseY(new Label("Name:"), enterName);
            InteractionDialog dlg = new InteractionDialog("Add Marker");
            dlg.getContentPane().add(wrapper);
            enterName.setDoneListener(e2->{
                String txt = enterName.getText();
                cnt.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false), cnt.getCoordAtPosition(e.getX(), e.getY()), enterName.getText(), "", e3->{
                    ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked "+txt, FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
                });
                dlg.dispose();
                tapDisabled = false;
            });
            dlg.showPopupDialog(new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 10, 100));
            enterName.startEditingAsync();
        });

        Button showNextForm = $(new Button("Next Form"))
                .addActionListener(e->{
                    Form form = new Form("Hello World");
                    Button b1 = $(new Button("B1"))
                            .addActionListener(e2->{
                                ToastBar.showMessage("B1 was pressed", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION);
                            })
                            .asComponent(Button.class);

                    Button back = $(new Button("Back to Home"))
                            .addActionListener(e2->{
                                home.showBack();
                            })
                            .asComponent(Button.class);
                    form.add(b1);
                })
                .asComponent(Button.class);

        FloatingActionButton nextForm = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESS_ALARM);

        nextForm.addActionListener(e->{
            Form form = new Form("Hello World");
            Button b1 = $(new Button("B1"))
                    .addActionListener(e2->{
                        ToastBar.showMessage("B1 was pressed", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION);
                    })
                    .asComponent(Button.class);

            Button back = $(new Button("Back to Home"))
                    .addActionListener(e2->{
                        home.showBack();
                    })
                    .asComponent(Button.class);
            form.add(b1).add(back);
            form.show();
        });



        Container root = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
                BorderLayout.center(nextForm.bindFabToContainer(cnt)),
                BorderLayout.south(
                        FlowLayout.encloseBottom(panTo, testCoordPositions, toggleTopMargin, btnMoveCamera, btnAddMarker, btnAddPath, btnClearAll )
                )
        );

        maps.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, root);
        maps.show();



        Form hi = new Form("Native Maps Test");
        hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        System.out.println("Read...");

        ReadParseJson x = new ReadParseJson();
        GoogleMapsTestApp e = new GoogleMapsTestApp();


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.getArray()));


        //create and build the home Form
        home = new Form("Home", BoxLayout.y());
        home.add(new Label("PetBnB: AirBnB for Pets!"));
        home.add(new Button("Search for Local Stay"));
        home.add(new Button("Payment"));

        TextField txt = new TextField("", "Enter Pet Animal here:");
        home.add(txt)
                .add(new CheckBox("New Users in Your Area!"));

        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Bnb Area 2");
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Bnb Area 3");
        rb1.setGroup("group");
        rb2.setGroup("group");

        home.addAll(rb1, rb2);

        final Slider a = new Slider();
        a.setText("50$");
        a.setProgress(50);
        a.setEditable(true);
        a.setRenderPercentageOnTop(true);
        home.add(a);

        Button b1 = new Button("WARNING: MUST READ");
        b1.addActionListener(evt -> Dialog.show("Warning!", "If Pet dies, it is not Bnb owner's responsibility", "Ok", "Cancel"));
        home.add(b1);

        //Create Form1 and Form2 and set a Back Command to navigate back to the home Form
        Form form1 = new Form("Search For Stay");
        setBackCommand(form1);
        Form form2 = new Form("Help");
        setBackCommand(form2);


        //Add navigation commands to the home Form
        NavigationCommand homeCommand = new NavigationCommand("Home");
        homeCommand.setNextForm(home);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(homeCommand);

        NavigationCommand cmd1 = new NavigationCommand("Search For Stay");
        cmd1.setNextForm(maps);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd1);

        NavigationCommand cmd2 = new NavigationCommand("Help");
        cmd2.setNextForm(form2);
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(cmd2);


        //Add Edit, Add and Delete Commands to the home Form context Menu
        Image im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_MODE_EDIT, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command edit = new Command("Edit", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Editing");

            }
        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(edit);

        im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_LIBRARY_ADD, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command add = new Command("Add", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Adding");
            }
        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(add);

        im = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_DELETE, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Command"));
        Command delete = new Command("Delete", im) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Deleting");
            }

        };
        home.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(delete);


        home.show();


    }


    protected void setBackCommand(Form f) {
        Command back = new Command("") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                home.showBack();
            }

        };
        Image img = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_BACK, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand"));
        back.setIcon(img);
        f.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar(back);
        f.getToolbar().setTitleCentered(true);
        f.setBackCommand(back);
    }

    boolean tapDisabled = false;

    public void stop() {

        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code so we can help you. Did you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: Here are the error messages I recieved in the console: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.googlemaps.InternalNativeMapsImpl
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1004)

Comment: Comments are not the place to post code: you can edit your own question and add the code there.

Comment: You've included a lot of code but it's unclear how the code relates to what we are seeing in the screenshot. It looks like you have some parsing code that might be encoding data incorrectly or it's possible you are using characters that aren't supported by the local font or Google might think you are in China and sends you the wrong text. I suggest narrowing down the test case to the essentials for us to understand. About the exception it essentially means the native maps aren't working, how did you integrate them into the IDE? Is that class under the lib hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Mr. Almog, What code should I put in to help you solve my problem. Thank you in advance for even reading this post, I know your a busy guy and this means a lot to me!